# HDD Plugged in to USB not readable in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive

I have a 1TB HDD running Windows 7 that failed to boot a few weeks ago. Not a single option worked for booting the drive, but that's a separate story. At the time, when I booted Ubuntu from a USB stick, I could still browse the files of the HDD with no problem.

Now, I have a new drive in my computer running Windows 10. Testing with two separate different devices for plugging a HDD in through USB, the file system in Windows presents me with 2 new drives:

```
System Reserved (D:) - 57.3 MB free of 99.9 MB
Local Disk (E:)
```

Browsing D drive shows nothing. Attempting to browse E drive gives the message

> E:\ is not accessible.
>
> The volume does not contain a recognized file system.
>
> Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted."

After a few minutes I am prompted to format E.

I'm trying to figure out how to read my HDD while plugged in via USB.

UPDATE:

Booting Ubuntu from usb and attempting to browse the HDD via USB I get:

> Unable to access "1.0 TB Volume"
>
> Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/ubuntu/
>
> 760403E90403AB67: Unknown Error when mounting /dev/sdb2

Booting Ubuntu from usb with HDD installed back in laptop internally and attempting to browse the drive now, Ubuntu gives me:

> Unable to access location
>
> Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ubuntu
>
> 760403E90403AB67: Unknown Error when mounting /dev/sda2

Answer (score 0):

The old Windows hard disk contains multiple partitions.
This worked fine as long as it was installed as an internal disk.

However, Windows does not support multiple partitions on removable media,
so once installed in a USB enclosure the second partition cannot be read.
The first partition is not interesting as it doesn't contain your data.

Your options as I see them are:

1. Install the disk as internal (if the computer case has that option)
2. Use Linux to read the data and transfer it to the new disk.

This is of course in the hope that the disk is not damaged.
If it is, you will need to use salvage tools.

Comment: Updated my question with Ubuntu attempts now. With HDD installed internally again, booting from Ubuntu stick, I'm getting errors quoted above. :( This last method was working fine previously. Could there be an easily fixable corruption issue now?

Comment: This is worrying, and I hope you have elsewhere some backups of the data. Better check the SMART data of the disk, if that's still possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by booting Ubuntu from USB, with problem HDD installed internally again.

From Ubuntu (19.04), I followed these instructions (https://askubuntu.com/a/513115/896224) to install the ntfs-3g package on my machine. After that, I ran `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2D` then my file browser was able to open and browse the contents of my HDD again!